# Knockout computed property not defined on second iteration

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I've got a sortable enumeration (draggable plugin that extends a foreach) over a collection of **CategoryModel** which has a **CanCategoryBeDeleted** computed method. This function is used to make a button enabled or not. **For the first item in the collection, it works**, but for the second one, it fails with the following error. All CategoryModel's in the collection look good. Taking the enable markup out renders the collection as expected.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "sortable: function
>   (){return { data:categories,afterMove:$root.orderCategories} }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "enable: function (){return
>   CanCategoryBeDeleted }" Message: CanCategoryBeDeleted is not defined

The markup is:

```
<div data-bind="sortable: { data: categories, afterMove: $root.orderCategories }">
    <div class="mb20">
        <div class="well well-sm moveCursor">
            <div class="fl">
                <span data-bind="visible: !$root.isCategorySelected($data)">
                    <a href="#" title="Edit name" data-bind="text: Name, click: $root.selectedCategory"></a>
                </span>
                <span data-bind="visibleAndSelect: $root.isCategorySelected($data)">
                    <input data-bind="value: Name, event: { blur: $root.clearCategory }" class="form-control" />
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="fr">
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.deleteCategory, enable: CanCategoryBeDeleted">Delete category</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        forum stuff here...
    </div>
</div>
```

The model is like this:

```
function CategoryModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
    self.Created = ko.observable(data.Created);
    self.IsPersisted = ko.observable(data.IsPersisted);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Order = ko.observable(data.Order);
    self.Forums = ko.observableArray(data.Forums);

    self.CanCategoryBeDeleted = ko.computed(function () {
        console.log("CanCategoryBeDeleted...");
        if (self.Forums().length == 0) {
            console.log("should enable");
            return true;
        }
        console.log("should not enable");
        return false;
    }, self);
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you maybe create a simplified repro in JSFiddle?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you provided that would cause this to fail. Also I don't really understand what you mean by "the second one". Can you try changing from `sortable` to `foreach` and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Amethi/cLLey9by/4/
Michael, I mean it renders the first item in the array, but no more, so it's erroring on the second array item. I'll have a play with foreach.

Comment: Same with foreach: http://jsfiddle.net/Amethi/qp83s25d/1/

Answer (score 0):

It was me being a doofus; I was enumerating simple js objects, not the category models. Once I converted the js objects to the model equivalent it worked.